# USB Debugging: How to revoke the "Always allow from this computer" option

Tags: android, eclipse, device, adt, offline

I've started developing for android. I'm using different computers with different operating systems. (A Windows desktop PC and a Macintosh at home and a Windows Notebook at work)

Most of the time I am using my desktop pc for development but since yesterday my Nexus 4 is displayed as offline in the Eclipse ADT Devices view. This problem only occurs on my desktop pc. On the other computers I don't have any problems getting the device online in eclipse.

I already tried a lot of things like:
- unplugging/plugging the nexus 4
- switching off/on usb debugging
- restarting computer, nexus 4 and the adb server
- reinstalling nexus 4 usb drivers (I'm using the Android Composite ADB Interface Drivers from the Android SDK)

I was about to give up but then I remembered something. After connecting the nexus via usb the "Allow USB debugging" dialog shows up and on my desktop pc I checked the "Always allow from this computer" option.

My hope is that disabling this "Always Allow"-permission could help to get my device back online. I already searched in the developer options to find a way to reset the "Always Allow" permission without success. Maybe it is possible to reset the permission by clearing the data of the App/Service (Settings->Apps(All)) which stores this information but I didn't find the name of it in Google.

So does anyone know the name of the App/Service whose data has to be cleared to reset the permission? Or is there another way to get the device back online that I have not tought of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your device with multiple computers with that enabled as well. I can use my Nexus 7 and Galaxy Nexus, both running 4.2.2 and having checked the always allow option on 3 machines right now.

Make sure all your machines are running the latest update for ADT and the SDK Tools, as the `adb` in the previous versions does not support the 4.2.2 security measures. One of my machines had the same problem, and it got fixed when I updated my tools.

Also, sometimes you have multiple Eclipse installs (I have about 11, for various reasons). If all of them aren't updated with the latest tools, make sure your `PATH` points to the `adb` in the newest update, and not any other.

Comment: Thanks a lot this has actually solved my problem. I found an environment variable which was set to a previous installed SDK Folder. I deleted that one and after reboot I was able to get my device back on.